# What is the meaning of 'battery' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Reuters wrote in this report](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-syria-russia-s-idUSKCN1241SR?il=0):

> The Russian Defence Ministry said on Tuesday it had deployed an S-300
>   missile system to its Tartus naval base in Syria.
>
> "The **missile battery** is intended to ensure the safety of the naval
>   base ... It is unclear why the deployment of the S-300 caused such
>   alarm among our Western partners," the ministry said in a statement.

It seems the word battery is referred to meant system here. Why is that?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: What @Mick said, and [what Google says](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=meaning+of+battery).

Comment: Battery:  "unit of artillery" (a sense recorded in English from 1550s).http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=battery

Comment: "Battery" basically means "multiple identical units".  (Which is why an "AAA battery" isn't -- technically it's "AAA cell".)  An artillery battery is multiple guns.  An auto battery is multiple individual cells.  A battery of lawyers is a bunch of guys dressed in identical suits.

Comment: Unless AAA=Anti Aircraft Artillery.

Answer (score 2):

This article is about artillery battery, which is a unit of guns, mortars, rockets or missiles so grouped to facilitate better battlefield communication and command and control, as well as to provide dispersion for its constituent gunnery crews and their systems. The term is also used in a naval context to describe groups of guns on warships.

The term 'battery' itself derives from the Middle French 'batterie', itself deriving from Old French 'baterie', the action of 'beating', which comes from Latin 'battuo', or 'beat'. The main purpose of massed guns was to target and destroy large fortifications (and later, as artillery became smaller, handier, and faster-firing, to do the same for massed formations of troops), that is, to 'beat' them, or 'batter' (observe the battering ram - similar principle).

You can read more in the [corresponding article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_battery).

Comment: Send in the battery of battering rams to batter the gates down!